# Find directories and files matching certain pattern and copy them with powershell

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching

I need to recreate project folders containing all article numbers acquired from a list.
It's searching for article names in the foldernames and inside the folders.

If the directory is found, it will copy the whole dir.
If a file matching the article is found, it will copy the parent dir.

Output:

```
Input the project name: iFLEX
Directory already exists.
File list already exists.
Folder: H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER.
Searching for files
Found [4011-511-28126]
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\H4011-511-281261 FRAME WELDED
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\H4011-511-281262 FRAME WELDED
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\H4011-511-281261 FRAME WELDED - Snelkoppeling.lnk
Failed to find dir [4011-511-18567]
Failed to find dir [4011-511-27747]
Found [4011-511-18803]
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\M4011-511-B-PARTS-2
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\M4011-511-B-PARTS-3
Found [4011-511-18812]
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\M4011-511-B-PARTS-2
Found in H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER\M4011-511-B-PARTS-3
```

I came up with the following code::

```
# Define the folder and files where we look for the files
$FilesFolder = 'H:\Sheetmetal\DMR\CUSTOMER'
$DestDir = 'K:\dxf'
$FileLocation = '.\files.txt'
$FolderDate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy")
$Depth = 5
$Project = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the project name'

# Test if dir exist or else create one
if (!(Test-Path "$DestDir\$Project-($FolderDate)"))
{
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$DestDir" -Name "$Project-($FolderDate)" > $null
   Write-Host "Created new file and text content added"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Directory already exists."
}

# Test if file exist or else create one
if (!(Test-Path "$FileLocation"))
{
   New-Item -name $FileLocation -type "file" -value "Input article to search for"
   Write-Host "Created new file and text content added"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "File list already exists."
}

# Start Notepad for generating list
$Proc = Start-Process Notepad.exe $FileLocation -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$Proc.WaitForExit()

# Define the list of files to check for
$FileNameList = Get-Content -Path $FileLocation 

# Get all the files in the FilesFolder
$ContainingFiles = Get-ChildItem $FilesFolder -Depth 1

Write-Host "Folder: $FilesFolder."
Write-Host "Searching for files"

# Go through each file in the FilesFodler
foreach ($FileName in $FileNameList) {

    # Define basename
    $BaseName = $FileName.Split("\\s+")[0]

    # Define name
    $Name = $FileName.Split("\\s+")[1]

    # If the folder contains a matching basename, write output GREEN
    If ($ContainingFiles.Name -like "*$BaseName*"){

        Write-Host "Found [$BaseName]" -ForegroundColor Green

        $FullName = Get-ChildItem "$FilesFolder" -Depth 1 | where {$_.name -match "$BaseName"} | %{$_.FullName}

        # Create another loop and copy files
        foreach ($FoundItem in $FullName) {

            # Split the directory structure to $depth
            $result = $FoundItem
            While (($result -split '\\' | ? { $_ }).Count -gt $Depth) {
                $result = Split-Path $result -Parent
            }

            # Split string for article name
            $founddir = $result.split('\')[-1]
        
            Write-Host "Found in $result"

            # Check if diretory already exists before copying
            if (!(Test-Path "$DestDir\$Project-($FolderDate)\$founddir"))
            {
                Copy-Item -Path "$result" -Destination "$DestDir\$Project-($FolderDate)\$founddir" -recurse -Force
            }
            
        }

    # If no matching basename was found, write output RED

    }Else{

        Write-Host "Failed to find dir [$BaseName]" -ForegroundColor Red

        }

    }

pause
```

I think (since I've no know-how of coding) it could be done way simpler or neater?